# weird behavior in sed pattern matching

Tags: sed, regular-expression

below two examples are expected behaviors. no problems
both "xxx2", "xxx@" match with "xxx." pattern.

```
$ echo abc1xxx2abc3abc4@111 | sed -rn 's/((abc.|xxx.){3}).*/\1/p'
abc1xxx2abc3

$ echo abc1xxx@abc3abc4@111 | sed -rn 's/((abc.|xxx.){3}).*/\1/p'
abc1xxx@abc3
```

also below two examples are expected behaviors.
both "xxx@", "xxxy" match with "xxx." pattern
but right next "@" char is not match for pattern so no output

```
$ echo abc1xxx@@abc3abc4@111 | sed -rn 's/((abc.|xxx.){3}).*/\1/p'
no output

$ echo abc1xxxy@abc3abc4@111 | sed -rn 's/((abc.|xxx.){3}).*/\1/p'
no output
```

but if i changed the "y" in the above example to "x" then
suddenly pattern is matched even though next char is "@"
I can't understand this behavior

```
$ echo abc1xxxx@abc3abc4@111 | sed -rn 's/((abc.|xxx.){3}).*/\1/p'
abc1xxxx@abc3abc4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change your pattern ever so slightly so that we can see what happens (just add `^.*` to the beginning so that the whole input line is replaced by the back reference):

```
$ echo abc1xxxx@abc3abc4@111 | sed -rn 's/^.*((abc.|xxx.){3}).*/\1/p'
xxx@abc3abc4
```

So it matches `xxx@` followed by `abc3` followed by `abc4`.  This is perfectly legal and expected since the pattern is looking for three occurrences of either `abc.` or `xxx.`.

The `abc1x` at the start of your output line was never affected by the pattern and therefore also never replaced by the substitution. It was just passed on from the input.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda.
I coudn't really think about that.
I just think right most greedy pattern ".*"